# PyTorch training from binary data

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

Given a decreasing function f(x,l) whose domain is [0,xmax], where l is a parameter, I want to write a program with PyTorch to learn the value of l from some binary-valued training data. The training data I have is (x_i,g(x_i)), i=1,2,...,n, where g(x)=1 when f(x)>t and otherise 0. The t here is a constant threshold value. I have defined the class

```py
class Function(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, l_init): # l is the parameter, its initial value is l_init
        self.l = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(l_init, dtype=float))
    def forward(self, x):
        return f(x) # here f is pre-defined
```

I also have a variable `train_data`, where `train_data[0]` is the array of x_i's (a float array) and `train_data[1]` is the array of g(x_i)'s (a 0/1 array). I instantiate the `Function` module:

```py
function = Function()
```

Define the loss function as

```py
loss_func = lambda x, y: (x - y) ** 2
```

For each training iteration, I compute `pred = function(train_data[0])`, and I have to compute the loss without losing the gradient function. But if I write

```py
loss = loss_func((pred > t).float(), train_data[0])
```

The gradient function will be lost. What should I do to use this binary training data to learn the value of l?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ZouJiu1/CNN_numpy/blob/master/net/loss.py#L36-L66

(pred > t) can not be derivated or loss the gradient information. (pred > t) should be used when you predict input. it should not be used when you train.

you can do this by using BCEloss with exp or BCEWithLogitsLoss without exp

you shoud define a loss function like this， the train_data should be one_hot format.

now assume pred is nx2 dimension

### **BCEloss**

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCELoss.html?highlight=bce#torch.nn.BCELoss

```
loss_func = torch.nn.BCEloss()
train_datas = torch.zeros_like(pred)
train_datas[torch.arange(len(pred)), train_data[1]] = 1
softmax = torch.nn.Softmax(pred, dim = -1)
pred = softmax(pred)
loss = loss_func(pred, train_datas)
```

when you predict the input, use

```
softmax = torch.nn.Softmax(pred, dim = -1)
pred = softmax(pred)
for i in range(len(pred)):
    if pred[i][0] > 0.6:
        label = 0
        ...do something...
    elif pred[i][1] > 0.6:
        label = 1
        ...do something...
```

### **BCEWithLogitsLoss**

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html?highlight=bce#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss

```
loss_func = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
train_datas = torch.zeros_like(pred)
train_datas[torch.arange(len(pred)), train_data[1]] = 1
loss = loss_func(pred, train_datas)
```

when you predict the input, use

```
softmax = torch.nn.Softmax(pred, dim = -1)
pred = softmax(pred)
for i in range(len(pred)):
    if pred[i][0] > 0.6:
        label = 0
        ...do something...
    elif pred[i][1] > 0.6:
        label = 1
        ...do something...
```

besides those, you can use crossentropyloss in multi classes classify too.
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html?highlight=cross#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss

#### another thing

above is assuming the pred is nx2, if pred is n dimension. you should use this loss function

```
loss_func = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
pred = torch.sigmoid(pred)
loss = loss_func(pred, train_data)
```

when you predict the input, use

```
softmax = torch.sigmoid(pred)
for i in range(len(pred)):
    if pred[i] > 0.6:
        ...do something...
        break
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please note that `train_data[0]` is a float array containing x_i's, so I don't quite understand the meaning of `train_datas[train_data[0]]`. Also, `train_data[1]` seems not to appear in your code, but it's crucial to compute the loss.

Comment: train_data[0] is input data, and train_data[1] is truth label.  I revise some statement.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Nevertheless, I still don't understand the `2` in `torch.zeros(2)`. `train_data[1]` is an `n`-dimensional vector, so `train_datas[train_data[1]]` may result in an index error.

Comment: I modify the codes according to your statement.

Comment: I appreciate your cooperation, but `train_datas` is an `n`-dimensional vector, and I think the statement `train_datas[torch.arange(len(pred)), train_data[1]]` will lead to an error. Could you please describe what you want to do in that line of code?

Comment: create one hot truth label, if train_data[1] = [0, 1, 0], then train_datas should be [[1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0]]

Comment: Well, `pred` is an `n`-dimersional vector, but `train_datas` is an `n x 2`-dimensional tensor.

Comment: if pred is n dimension, I update the codes and statement